# Не записываются данные из формы в таблицу БД

Tags: php, sqlite

Ошибок не выводит, но данные не пишет из формы таблицу БД.

Вот код:

```php
public function add(Post $post): void
{

$dateAdded = date('d.m.Y');

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, content, dateAdded) VALUES (':title', ':content', '$dateAdded')";

    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $req->bindValue(':title', $post->getTitle(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req->bindValue(':content', $post->getContent(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $req->execute();
}
```

Структура данных:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `title` TEXT,
    `content`   TEXT,
    `dateAdded` TEXT,
    `dateModified`  TEXT
);
```

Comment: Проверяли входные данные? может переменная `$post` пустая?

Comment: Тут нечего проверять, а мануал надо открыть и прочитать его внимательно. Тогда может станет понятно как __правильно__ вставлять плейсхолдеры в текст запроса.

Comment: Нет, $post не пустая, из формы передаётся, но, почему-то не пишет в БД.

Comment: 1. Выведите на экран получившийся текст вопроса. 2. Посмотрите что у вас записывается в базу. сделайте select * from posts.

Comment: Так, ведь, в том то и дело, что туда ничего не записывается.

Answer (score 5):

Вот полностью рабочий пример (Протестировано)
Параметры:
`YourDB` заменить на имя Вашей базы
`YourHost` заменить на `ip` Вашей базы
`YourName` заменить на Имя пользователя `mysql`
`YourPass` заменить на Пароль пользователя `mysql`

```php
$post1 = 'val1';
$post2 = 'val2';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YourDB;host=YourHost', 'YourName', 'YourPass');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$dateAdded = date('d.m.Y');

$sql = "INSERT INTO `posts` (title, content, dateAdded) VALUES (:title, :content, '$dateAdded')";

$req = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$req->bindValue(':title', $post1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$req->bindValue(':content', $post2, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$req->execute();
```

Проверьте обязательно получение Ваших параметров `$post->getTitle()` и `$post->getContent()`.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как проверить эти параметры?

Comment: @Linne Выведите их через `print_r($post->getTitle());` И проверить тип данных. При запросе в БД они не должны быть массивами. Если это массив, то перевести в строку.

Comment: App\Model\Post Object ( [title:App\Model\Post:private] => Заголовок бла-бла-бла… [content:App\Model\Post:private] => Текст бла-бла… [dateAdded:App\Model\Post:private] => [dateModified:App\Model\Post:private] => [id:protected] => [errors:protected] => Array ( ) ) Заголовок бла-бла-бла…Текст бла-бла…

Comment: @Linne, чтобы проверить является ли Ваше значение строкой - добавьте `is_string($post->getTitle());` Если `true`, то строка, если `false`, то нет. А у Вас скорее всего это просто объекты.

Comment: Добавил, выводит то же самое. Это true? :) (прошу прощения, ежели вопрос дурацкий)

Comment: @Linne если полностью, то напишите вот так: `print(is_string($post->getTitle()) ? 'true' : 'false');` Нет, Вам необходимо получить прям значение. У Вас же сейчас выводятся объекты. Попробуйте, проверьте.

Comment: App\Model\Post Object ( [title:App\Model\Post:private] => Заголовок бла-бла-бла… [content:App\Model\Post:private] => Текст бла-бла-бла… [dateAdded:App\Model\Post:private] => [dateModified:App\Model\Post:private] => [id:protected] => [errors:protected] => Array ( ) ) true. Стало быть, тру. Только почему то выводится и content

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104548/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-linne).

Answer (score 1):

Плейсхолдеры в запросе не нужно экранировать, экранируйте только строку которую инжектите:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, content, dateAdded) VALUES (:title, :content, '$dateAdded')";
```

Читаем [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: Нет, не удаётся(( ВВот вывод var_dump($req): PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) object(PDOStatement)#37 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(85) "INSERT INTO posts (title, content, dateAdded) VALUES (:title, :content, '10.01.2020')" }

Comment: Нужно посмотреть ```$req->rowCount()```

Comment: Вывод $req->rowCount() пустой.

Comment: Должно быть число - либо `0`, либо `1`. Сделайте так:  `$count = $req->rowCount(); print("Number of inserted rows: $count");`

Comment: Number of inserted rows: 0

Comment: Вывод print_r($post); — App\Model\Post Object ( [title:App\Model\Post:private] => Заголовок [content:App\Model\Post:private] => текст текст текст [dateAdded:App\Model\Post:private] => [dateModified:App\Model\Post:private] => [id:protected] => [errors:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Попробуйте забиндить просто текст, как-то так: `$req->bindValue(':title', "test title");   $req->bindValue(':content', "test content");`, меня смущает ваша модель данных. Что за фреймворк? Нужно больше кода.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, не удаётся :( А это по-сути и не фреймворк, это получился форк, этакая адаптация с урезанным функционалом чей-то поделки с гитхаба :) Собственно вот: https://github.com/mcoudurier/simple-mvc-blog. Мне нужно это для работы с SQLite, а там используются конструкции, которые не работают в этой БД, приходится искать замену и несколько переделывать код.

Comment: Мда..., тут целый муравейник. Беглым взглядом заметил, что проект для `MySQL`, что уже плохо. Я бы на всякий случай убедился, что таблицы действительно созданы. К сожалению сейчас больше времени нет, возможно ещё раз взгляну завтра.